# Website won't load in android webview but works fine in android browsers

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-intent, webview

This has been annoying me for a while now and I could really use some help. I have a website created on portfoliobox.net which works fine in chrome and every other browser I tried on android (actual phones, not emulators), however I wanted to make it into an app for part of a University project. My webview app loads other websites fine but not mine for some reason, so yes I have set the permissions right and I have javascript enabled. It could be something simple but I'm a major noob and haven't got much of a clue.

Here is the logcat

```
04-30 22:08:56.954: W/BindingManager(8365): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8365
04-30 22:08:56.962: E/com.parse.push(8365): successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
04-30 22:08:56.973: D/GCM(2579): COMPAT: Multi user ser=0 current=0
04-30 22:08:56.989: D/GCM(11959): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
04-30 22:08:57.145: I/Icing(2579): Indexing DBC59092704C7216FC04EAC8683F4EE7F5C1F3E0 from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
04-30 22:08:57.302: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2579): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-30 22:08:57.302: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2579): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-30 22:08:57.306: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2579): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-30 22:08:57.333: I/Icing(2579): Indexing done DBC59092704C7216FC04EAC8683F4EE7F5C1F3E0
04-30 22:08:57.333: D/PowerManagerService(912): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=289528107 [Icing], flags=0x0
04-30 22:08:57.377: D/PowerManagerService(912): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=1014891468, flags=0x1, tag="NetworkStats", ws=null, uid=1000, pid=912
04-30 22:08:57.406: D/PowerManagerService(912): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=1014891468 [NetworkStats], flags=0x0
04-30 22:08:58.035: I/chromium(8365): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'webkitIDBRequest' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBRequest' instead.", source:  (0)
04-30 22:08:58.270: I/chromium(8365): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "HARD RESET!!", source: http://www.broadbentstudios.com/application/_output/pb.out.front.js?v=7 (1)
04-30 22:08:58.277: I/chromium(8365): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of null", source: http://www.broadbentstudios.com/application/_output/pb.out.front.js?v=7 (1)
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
      android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
      android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/customscroll">
     </WebView>


</LinearLayout>
```

BroadbentStudios.java

```
package com.broadbentstudios;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;

public class BroadbentStudios extends Activity {

    WebView webView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.broadbentstudios.com/");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }



        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView!=null && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    {

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }

}
```

I also use Parse for push notifications for new content but I tried a clean webview app without it too and that didn't work so I'm pretty sure it's not that.

I would think that because it works fine in browsers it is my app messing up somewhere, but I could be wrong I guess. any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's my website and not my app, it would be good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I've been searching for about 2 months for an answer to this and as soon as I come here for help I find it myself haha, typical. Anyway, for anybody in a similar situation, as well as enabling javascript you also need to enable Dom storage by adding in;

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Change webView to whatever yours is called and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: doesnt work for me. i just have couple of locally loaddata webviews.